# Cannot determine main class after importing

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse on a Mac. I'm learning java - previously used python.

Originally created a new package and it worked fine, using public static void main(String[] args)

In a separate package, I added acm.jar to my build path.  That works fine: import acm.program.* and I use public void run()

Now my original package foo gives me an error:
Exception in thread "main" acm.util.ErrorException: Cannot determine the main class.
    at acm.program.Program.main(Program.java:1358)
acm.jar isn't in my build path for foo. Do I have to remove acm.jar from all my packages?

Comment: By package are you talking about Java packages? I'm not sure how you add a jar to a build path of a Java package...  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Comment: Sorry: new to Java. I added ACM to my build path for a Java Project.

Details:
In Eclipse, Package Explorer, I right click on an existing Java Project, Scroll down to Build Path: Configure Build Path. This brings up a new window, under Java Build path, I added an external JAR (ACM).

Once I added ACM to a build path for one Java Project, my previous working Java Projects no longer worked, and gave me the Exception in thread "main".